# From command line without internet how to install software from the installation DVD?

Tags: server, package-management

I don't have an internet connection. I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 server on one machine. From the command line appreciate your help for how to select/install additional software and/or libraries from the installation DVD media?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried out this solution, but this is what I found after a bit of googling.

Run the command

> sudo apt-cdrom add

Insert the Disc and follow the instructions (it will ask you to name each disc). When `apt-cdrom` is finished with the disc, eject it with

> eject

Once the last disc is done, enter this code in the Terminal:

> sudo apt-get update

followed by

> sudo apt-get upgrade

which will update your system if any newer files are available.

**[Source](http://www.ubuntux.org/node/9502)**

Comment: Good, the "sudo apt-cdrom add" command mounted the content of the cdrom int /media/cdrom directory also checked integrity of the media. What would be the command line for getting the software tree structure selection and/or navigation list. This is usually displayed when we do manual software packages during installation. I think there should be a command line for getting it. Thanks for your follow up.

Comment: @Germinus: `aptitude` (which you may have to install first, `apt-get install aptitude`)

Answer (score 0):

When you Install packages using internet on system connected with internet , .deb packages download at **var/cache/apt/archieve** . You can simply copy this packages in folder and  go to system without Internet.

Open terminal just type 
`sudo dpkg -i`
  Drop and drag those copied packages in terminal.

You will get packages installed on system.

You just need to care that both systems must have same architecture whether it is i386 or amd64.